# TYPEORM migration issue, migration generated, but cannot run them

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, migration, typeorm

I have issues with typeorm migrations, so I cannot run generated migrations.

I have issue with typeorm migrations. I can generate migration files, but when I try to run them, typeorm cli shows this message: "No migrations are pending" and it creates **migrations** table on postgres.

I have wrote migrations directory in data source like that: `migrations: ["src/database/migrations/*.ts"]`

Folder Structure [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IG90.png)

Please, let me know if you know problem and how to solve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have opened your terminal in the right path?

If yes, I suggest you to run:

```
typeorm migration:show
```

It checks if the migration has already been applied. If it doesn't work, try to check if you database connection is right.

Comment: I have tried this command, but it shows nothing. Database connection is okay, so I can reach db with datasource and it works when make true synchronize option. But main problem related with migrations. It does not insert generated migrations to table.